# Binder vs. sequestrant

Tags: difference

Are the words "binder" and "sequestrant" synonyms?
I think they are, as I'm translating a document about mycotoxin sequestrants, but I'm more arts than science, so need confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do some research on this one.  The short answer is that, in the context of food additives, while *sequestrant* has some properties associated with *binders*, it also has additional properties as a preservative.  A *binder* simply helps maintain the stability and cohesion of the food.

In this context I would assume you are talking about the properties of some sequestrants to remove mycotoxins from food?  If so I would be careful to use them as synonyms for each other. If you are specifically talking about the *binding* properties of sequestrants, it might be fine, but otherwise I think it's such a specialized term that I wouldn't replace it with anything else.

Note that in this context, these are not common English terms.  "Binder" is of course, a common word but not usually as a substance used to cohere food for long-term consistency.  That would be more an industry-specific use.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly the information I was looking for and confirms my original thoughts.